# Does a normal ordered Hamiltonian admit the same solutions as the non-normal ordered Hamiltonian

Tags: second-quantization, klein-gordon-equation

I'm reading "Lectures of Quantum Field Theory" by Ashok Das, where I encountered for the first time the normal ordering of an Hamiltonian (Chapter 5.5). In the book, the Hamiltonian for the Klein-Gordon equation (in second quantization) is
$$
H = \int d^3k \frac{E_k}{2} \left(a\left(\vec{k}\right)a^\dagger\left(\vec{k}\right)+a^\dagger\left(\vec{k}\right)a\left(\vec{k}\right)\right)
$$
for $a^\dagger,a$, raising and lowering operators (respectively).
The normal ordered Hamiltonian is then
$$
H^{\mathtt{N.O.}}=\int d^3k E_ka^\dagger\left(\vec{k}\right)a\left(\vec{k}\right)
$$

I understand that we needed a way to remove the negative energy solutions, but the book doesn't expand on why the new Hamiltonian is a "proper" candidate that admits positive energy eigenvectors and not negative ones. Even worse, in the next section, commutation relations between the lowering and raising operators and the Hamiltonian are taken as the same as with the non-normal ordered Hamiltonian without explanation.

Let $\left| E \right>$ be a positive energy solution of the original Hamiltonian: $H\left| E\right>=E\left| E\right>$. How can I show that $H^{\mathtt{N.O}}\left| E\right>=E\left| E\right>$, or the weaker proposition (where the energy is not the same) $H^{\mathtt{N.O}}\left| E\right>=E'\left| E\right>$ where $E'>0$?

What I tried was to use the relation:
$$
\left[a\left(\vec{k}\right),a^\dagger\left(\vec{k'}\right)\right]=\delta^3\left(\vec{k}-\vec{k'}\right)
$$
To rewrite the N.O. Hamiltonian as:
$$
H^{\mathtt{N.O.}} = H - \int d^3 k \frac{E_k}{2} \left[a\left(\vec{k}\right),a^\dagger\left(\vec{k}\right)\right]
$$
But then we have $\delta^3(0)$ in an integral over the entire $k$-space.

Comment: Shouldn't the normal ordered hamiltonian have the annihilation operators to the right?

Comment: You are correct, I fixed it

Comment: You have shown already that the two operators differ by a multiple (read infinity) times the identity. This is why commutation relations stay the same. To deal properly with the infinity you need to introduce a cutoff etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a system of $k=1, \ldots, N$ uncoupled harmonic oscillators with angular frequencies $\omega_k$. The Hamiltonian $H$, expressed in terms of ladder operators $a_k$ and $a_k^\dagger$ satisfying the commutation relations $[a_k, a_\ell^\dagger]=\delta_{k \ell} \mathbf{1}$, $[a_k,a_\ell]=0$, is given by $$H= \sum\limits_{k=1}^N \frac{\omega_k}{2} \left(a_k a_k^\dagger+a_k^\dagger a_k \right)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \omega_k\left(a_k^\dagger a_k +\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{1}\right), \tag{1} \label{1}$$ where the commutation relation $a_k a_k^\dagger= a_k^\dagger a_k +\mathbf{1}$ was used to arrive at the second form of the Hamiltonian. As the groundstate (the state of lowest energy) $|0\rangle$ of this sytem is characterized by $$a_k |0\rangle=0 \quad \forall \; k=1,\ldots, N, \tag{2} \label{2}$$ the ground state energy $E_0$ (i.e. the smallest eigenvalue of $H$) is given by $$ E_0=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \omega_k, \tag{3} \label{3}$$ sometimes also referred to as the so-called zero-point energy. As only energy *differences* are physically relevant (at least as long as we do not couple our system to the gravitational field), we are free to reset our energy scale by an arbitrary value. A convenient choice is, of course, to readjust our energy scale in such a way that the ground state energy of our system vanishes. This corresponds to defining a *normal ordered* Hamiltonian $$ H_{\rm no}= \sum\limits_{k=1}^N \omega_k a_k^\dagger a_k =H-E_0 \mathbf{1}, \tag{4} \label{4}$$ obtained from $H$ by subtracting $E_0 \mathbf{1}$. Equivalently, $H_{\rm no}$ can be obtained from the original Hamiltonian $H$ by writing all annihilation operators $a_k$ to the *right* of the creation operators $a_k^\dagger$ ($=$ normal ordering).

This strategy becomes particularly relevant in the limit $N \to \infty$, corresponding to a system with an infinite number of harmonic oscillators. In the case, \eqref{3} diverges and the readjustment of the ground state energy becomes mandatory.

After these introductory remarks, it is now easy to understand the system described by the free Klein-Gordon field by employing the replacements $$k \to \vec{k}, \quad \sum\limits_k \to \int d^3k, \quad a_k \to a(\vec{k}), \quad a_k^\dagger\to a^\dagger(\vec{k}), \quad\delta_{k\ell} \to \delta^{(3)}(\vec{k}-\vec{\ell}). \tag{5} \label{5}$$ The ground state energy of the Hamiltonian *before* normal ordering is, as you had correctly noticed, badly divergent, but this is easily cured by introducing $$H_{\rm no} =\int d^3k \, \omega(\vec{k}) a^\dagger(\vec{k}) a(\vec{k}) \tag{6} \label{6}$$ with $H_{\rm no} |0\rangle =0$, as the ground state $|0\rangle$ is defined by $$a(\vec{k}) |0\rangle=0 \quad \forall \; \vec{k}. \tag{7} \label{7}$$ Energy-momentum eigenstates $|\vec{p}\rangle$, $|\vec{p}_1, \vec{p}_2 \rangle, \ldots$ with $1,2,\ldots$ particles are now constructed by successively applying the creation operator on the ground state. As an example, let us consider the one-particle energy-momentum eigenvector (better: eigendistribution) $|\vec{p}\rangle$, defined by $$|\vec{p} \rangle := a^\dagger(\vec{p}) |0\rangle, \tag{8} \label{8}$$ with the eigenvalue equation $$\begin{align} H_{\rm no}|\vec{p} \rangle &=\int \!d^3k \,\omega(\vec{k}) \,  a^\dagger(\vec{k})\,  a(\vec{k})\,  a^\dagger(\vec{p}) |0\rangle \\ &= \int\! d^3k \, \omega(\vec{k})\,a^\dagger(\vec{k})\,  \underbrace{\left[a(\vec{k}), a^\dagger(\vec{p})\right]}_{\delta^{(3)}(\vec{k}-\vec{p})}|0\rangle\\ &= \omega(\vec{p})  a^\dagger(\vec{p}) |0\rangle =\omega(\vec{p}) |\vec{p}\rangle.  \end{align} \tag{9}$$

Comment: What I found weird about this example, is that in the finite case you have a "zero" state which you move to the zero energy level. In the infinite case, no such minimum energy state exists. After rescaling the zero level energy emerges "out of a hat".

Comment: @YotamOhad If you feel more comfortable, you could "regularize" $H$ by introducing some momentum "cut-off" $\Lambda$ making $E_0(\Lambda)>0$ finite. As $H_{\rm reg}$ is the sum of a positive operator and $E_0(\Lambda)$, the ground state exists of course, given by $a(\vec{k}) |0\rangle=0$. This is a (very simple) example of the necessity of "renormalization" occuring at various instances in (relativistic) quantum field theory. As the absolute value of energy has no physical meaning, you are free to *redefine* the energy of the vacuum to be $0$ sending $\Lambda \to \infty$ afterwards .